# validating wsdl/schema using cxf

Tags: java, validation, wsdl, cxf

I am having a hard time getting cxf to validate an xml request that my service creates for a 3rd party.

My project uses maven. Here is my project structure

Main Module :

+ Sub-Module1 = Application

+ sub-Module2 = Interfaces

In Interfaces, inside src/main/resources I have my wsdl and xsd.
so, src/main/resources
        + mywsdl.wsdl.
        + myschema.xsd

The interface submodule is listed as a dependency in the Application-sub-module.
inside Application sub-module, there is a cxsf file in src/maim/resources.

```
<jaxws:client name="{myTargerNameSpaceName}port"
    createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

AND:.

```
    <jaxws:endpoint name="{myTargetNameSpaceName}port"
    wsdlLocation="/mywsdl.wsdl"
    createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

I tried changing the "name="{myTargetNameSpaceName}port" to "name="{myEndPointName}port"

But to no anvil.

My application works. But it just do not validate the xml I am producing that has to be consumed by a 3rd party application.
I would like to get the validation working, so that any request that I send would be a valid one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that the value of the name attribute is {NAMESPACE}PORT_NAME where NAMESPACE is your namespace URI and PORT_NAME is the name of your WSDL port.  Without seeing your WSDL, I don't know if you named your WSDL port "port" or if you are just giving a sanitized example.

For example, my WSDL namespace is "http://example.com/services" and the name of my WSDL port element is "myPort", the Spring configuration would look like this

```
<jaxws:endpoint name="{http://example.com/services}myPort" >
  ...
```

See "CreatedFromAPI" attribute description in [CXF docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html)

If that doesn't solve your problem, try looking at the [wsdl_first](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/tags/cxf-2.2.7/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first/) example code, upgrading your CXF version, and/or posting your question with test code demonstrating your issue to the [CXF user list](http://cxf.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

Comment: Thank you for  your response. :)

<quote>
Without seeing your WSDL, I don't know if you named your WSDL port "port" or if you are just giving a sanitized example
</quote>
My bad. I had sanitized the name, but forgot to add "my" as a prefix to make it "myPort".

I have given it exactly as you have listed it. However I am using version 2.1.3. I shall check if I can use a newer version and also study the example to see if it will help me understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `@org.apache.cxf.annotations.SchemaValidation` annotation on your service implementation class and schema validation will work.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues.  CXF 2.3.1 fixed the issue for us on incoming messages but not outgoing messages.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3233

We work around it by marshaling the messages and validating them within the server before sending them out through the CXF interceptor chain.  We validate using org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidator.

I'm hoping a future version of CXF will solve this but this is what we do for now.